# Starting a SharePoint Workflow in One Click

Tags: 2007, workflow, list

I have a list in SharePoint 2007 with a Workflow bound to it.  No parameters required to start the workflow.  What I'd like to do is create a column in one of the views with either a button or hyperlink that could start the workflow right away.  Has anyone ever figured out how to do this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this post: [Send email with javascript – with the help of a workflow in a dedicated “send email-list”](http://sharepointjavascript.wordpress.com/2010/06/16/send-email-with-javascript-with-the-help-of-a-workflow-in-a-dedicated-send-email-list/)